# How can I add an extra line in a plotly parallel coordinates plot connecting two of the data rows?

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, plotly-python

I have some data in a 2D array that I plot in a parallel coordinates plot using plotly:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Sample data for the parallel coordinate plot (2D array with 4 columns)
data = [
    [1, 10, 5, 15],
    [2, 8, 7, 12],
    [3, 12, 6, 18],
    [4, 6, 8, 11],
    [5, 9, 10, 16]
]

# Create the parallel coordinate plot using go.Parcoords
fig = go.Figure(go.Parcoords(
    line=dict(color='blue'),
    dimensions=list([
        dict(range=[1, 5], label='A', values=[row[0] for row in data]),
        dict(range=[6, 12], label='B', values=[row[1] for row in data]),
        dict(range=[5, 10], label='C', values=[row[2] for row in data]),
        dict(range=[11, 18], label='D', values=[row[3] for row in data])
    ])
))

# Show the plot
fig.show()
```

This results in this plot:
[Parallel Coordinates plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzR6m.png)

Now, I would like to add a line connecting two of the data rows. Like this:
[Parallel Coordinates plot with connected lines.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5ftW.png)

How can I achive this?

I have tried adding the following right before `fig.show()`:

```
trace1_coords = data[1]
trace2_coords = data[3]
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=['D', 'D'], y=[trace1_coords[3], trace2_coords[3]], mode='lines', line=dict(color='red')))
```

... thinking it would result in at least a straight line on the 4th axis of the plot. However, it resulted in:
[Parallel Plot with wrong line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZkkq.png)

What can I do better?